# TID-owrsuwi8g WARN: NameError: uninitialized constant NewsWorker in Sidekiq of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I am developing `Rails` application where send emails using `Sidekiq gem`.

Create worker then call it like:

```
Worker File: news_worker.rb

NewsWorker.perform_at(5.minutes.from_now, @news.title, @news.link, @news.image, user_detail.email, user_detail.category_name, type, email_template)
```

But anyhow its not working and show `error message` like:

```
TID-owrsuwi8g WARN: NameError: uninitialized constant NewsWorker
```

I tried to call from Model and Controller as well but still display same error. `My old worked running fine` but why this new create not working.. I found many ways but still not sortout.

---

### Update

```
# /app/workers/news_worker.rb

class NewsWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def perform  news_title, news_link, news_image, email, category_name, type, email_template = nil
    send_to_email(news_title, news_link, news_image, email, category_name, type, email_template)
  end

  def send_to_email news_title, news_link, news_image, email, category_name, type, email_template
    SchoolMailer.send_news(news_title, news_link, news_image, email, category_name, type, email_template).deliver
  end
end
```

Let me know if any one have idea.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide the full path of `news_worker` file, and code inside (mainly class definition)?

Comment: Sounds like Sidekiq isn't loading the Rails environment, are you running sidekiq from within the Rails root directory?

Comment: @AhmedSamirShahin
app/workers/news_worker.rb  also update question with full code.

Comment: Did you restart Sidekiq?

Comment: @MikePerham its auto start once push code.

Answer (score -1):

I think it has something to do with `autoload_paths`; the `workers` directory is not auto-loaded.

In `config/application.rb` add the following line:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/workers)
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Rails autoloads everything in `app/`

Comment: Depending on Rails version :) ?